# Fortran 90, Compiling program: Error messages

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to figure out these error messages:

**Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: Missing RECL parameter in OPEN statement**

but I have no ideas what these messages means....
First of all, what is "-ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full" mean?
Also, what is "RECL parameter" ?

Could anyone explain to me, please?
That will help me a lot.

Please forgive my English, English is my second language.

Yuuka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What operating system and compiler?

In any case, what it's saying is that you've got an OPEN statement in the program that has parameters that make it require a RECL (record length) parameter and it doesn't have one.

The other part says it can't tell you where in the program it happened.  if you add one of those flags, then recompile, you'll get more information.

It kind of looks like it could be the Intel compiler, in which case [this man page](http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/ohp/header_ohMIF_10.html) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I don't know what compiler I'm using actually.
My friend download it for me and set up.

I will try to do these things. thank you so much for your help!