# Why on Fortran code, one should use units bigger than 10?

Tags: fortran

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691760/2754579) answer it is recommended that in a fortran code, one should not open files on units smaller than 10 (I understood its suggestion about using the `newunit` identifier). I looked in [this](http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-python) best practices guide and found nothing about this. So, is there a deeper reason for this or just a style recommedation to avoid people opening units 5 and 6?

Comment: So yes, it is to avoid 5 or 6, or their equivalents if the processor uses other numbers than 5 and 6. Historically, there were more special units than standard-input and standard-output, you had terminals, line printers, tapes, punch card readers... They sometimes had some magic low number and you did not want to hit it.

Comment: This is completely compiler dependent : Eg. the [CF90 Cray compiler](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3695-35/html-S-3695-35/pdollsmg.html) states : _Unit numbers 100, 101, and 102 are permanently associated with the standard input, standard output, and standard error files, respectively. These files can be referenced on READ and WRITE statements. A CLOSE statement on these unit numbers has no effect. An INQUIRE statement on these unit numbers indicates they are nonexistent (not valid)._

Comment: @kvantour Exactly this is linked in my answer in that link :)

Comment: @kvantour BTW that does NOT mean that the compiler you link wouldn't pre-connect units 0,5 and 6. it DOES pre-connect them. It is all in your link. The point is that even if you connect unit 5 or 6 to something else, the pre-connected file still remains connected, because it is also pre-connected to unit 101 or 102 *at the same time*.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, I am aware of this. I just posted this here as a counterexample why "one should use units bigger than 10" is invalid. Also the cray compiler is the first compiler I encounter with pre-connect unit numbers different then the classic 0,5 and 6. Furthermore, is the behaviour of the pre-connected units 100,101 and 102 actually allowed by the standard (i.e. you cannot close them)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and to pointing out a question with the answer. It did not occurred to me to search specifically why not open on units 5 and 6, as I already suspected that opening on these units would not be a good idea.